# Excel graph date and count

Tags: excel, graph

I have a list of date+times and a count for each, eg:

```
Date/Time             Count
6/19/12 3:00 AM         1
6/19/12 4:00 AM         1
6/19/12 5:00 AM        79
6/19/12 6:00 AM       322
6/19/12 7:00 AM       275
6/19/12 8:00 AM       143
```

I would like to graph based on hour but when I select the data and graph it excel groups all the hours in the day together.  I would like to see the trend as time passes.  What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the axis as a Text axis - Excel wants to format it as a Date axis, which has a minimum resolution of 1 day

[image]

Comment: Not true, you can just change the resolution from "number" and use numbers < 1, like 0,04166666666666666666666666666667 for 1 hour (1/24).

Answer (score 0):

I did some testing and what I did was plot the graph using the data that I had then changing the format of the date column to general number which gave me my trendline and then changing the format of the horizontal access datevalues in the chart to the date format.  There must be an easier way though this works for now.  Using Excel 2010.